# "string cannot be converted to integer"

Tags: java, string, integer, int

In my QuestionnaireUI.java class

```
private void btnProceedActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        tblResults.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        int temp = tblResults.getSelectedRow();
        Global.manu = tblResults.getValueAt(temp, 1).toString();
        Global.mod = tblResults.getValueAt(temp, 2).toString();
        Global.price = "R" +     (Integer)tblResults.getValueAt(temp,3).toString();  //line of code that gives me the error message

        this.dispose();
        new PaymentUI().setVisible(true);
    }
```

In my Global.java class that I use for all my global variables

```
    public class Global {

   public static int rowSelect;
   public static String manu;
   public static String mod;
   public static int price;
   public static int financeprice;
   public static int rate = 9;

}
```

Comment: After Java 5 `.toString()` is not needed, as autoboxing will convert it to `String`...

Comment: How sould `R` be converted to an int?

Comment: BTW: properties should not be public. You should make them private and accesss through getter and setter

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Auto-boxing does not automatically convert integers to strings; it just automatically boxes primitive types such as `int` into its corresponding wrapper object `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are Adding `R` (a String) to `(Integer)tblResults.getValueAt(temp,3).toString()`

There are a few issues here:

`tblResults.getValueAt(temp,3).toString()` returns a String, which is not an integer so can not be cast to an integer.

Adding a String to anything will always give you a String, so `"R" + something` will always return a String. which you are then trying to assign to an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

As the `+` operator with `String` as one of the arguments converts the other argument to `String`:

```
Global.price = "R" + tblResults.getValueAt(temp,3);
```

Unless `price` declared as `int` in which case:

```
Global.price = (Integer)tblResults.getValueAt(temp,3);
```